# JAXB unmarshal child attributes without creation of child class

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I want to unmarshal a (simplified) XML structure like this:

```
<parent>
    <a>AValue</a>
    <b>BValue</b>
    <c someAttribute = "true">CValue</c>
</parent>
```

I know how to do this with declaring a class C like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "c", propOrder = {
        "someAttribute"
    })
public class C{
    @XmlValue
    private String c;
    @XmlAttribute ( name="someAttribute")
    private boolean someAttribute;
    //getters and setters
}
```

And getting it as a member in class parent like this:

```
public class Parent{
   private String a;
   private String b;
   private C c;
   //getters and setters for c,b,a
}
```

This works finde and i can access the value of `C` via `parent.getC().getC();`
My Question **is how to achieve that i do not have to create a class `C`** and get the `value` and `attribute` of `C` as a member of `parent`, without editing the `parent` Pojo with new members and other getters and setters.
I already tried to do this via Listeners and searched for similar structures, but i haven't got any ideas left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out how to achieve this.
Its necessary to use the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` Annotation and mark the C class as an `@XmlRootElement` as well as an `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`.
Furthermore one need to use the `@XmlTransient` on the getter of the String member which was annotated with `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`.

**Full solution:**

Class C:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class C{
    @XmlValue
    private String c;

    @XmlAttribute
    private boolean someAttribute;
    //getters and setters for both
```

Class Adapter:

```
public class Adapter extends XmlAdapter<C, String> {

    public String unmarshal(C pC) throws Exception {
        //some possible handling with the attribute over pC.getSomeAttribute();
        return pC.getC();
    }

    public C marshal(String pC) throws Exception {
       C c = new C();
       c.setC(pC)
       //some possible handling to set the attribute to c
       return c;
    }
```

Class Parent:

```
public class Parent{
   private String a;
   private String b;
   @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(Adapter.class)
   private String c;

   @XmlTransient
    public String getC() {
        return c;
    }
   //getters and setters for b,a and setter for C
}
```